# Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $(p^n)m$, where $p$ is a prime and $m$ is not divide by $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $P = \{a\in G\mid a^{p^k} = e\text{ for some $k$ depending on $a$}\}$.

Prove that

(a) $P$ is a subgroup of $G$.

(b) $G/P$ has no elements of order $p$.

(c) order of $P=p^n$.

Comment: @Gregory Grant:  I made I minor change to your edits, replacing $p_k$ by $p^k$, which I presume is what you and our OP S. H. Choi intended. It seems contextually justified.  Am I correct? I hope so!  Cheers!

Comment: P is a subset of G by definition of P.  It is non-empty since $e^{p^0}=e$, so the identity is in there.  What about the rest of the subgroup test?

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you, I should have caught that

Comment: @Gregory Grant:  happens to all of us.   You are more than welcome!

Comment: Thanks for editing problem, mistyping;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing a subgroup isn't too bad. Note $P$ is nonempty as $e\in P$. Also, $a_1,a_2\in P$ with $p^k,p^m$ such that $a^{p^k}=e=a^{p^m}$ and $(a_1a_2^{-1})^{p^{m+k}}=e$ since $G$ is abelian.

If some element $\bar{x}$ was of order $p$ in $G/P$, then $x\in P$ so $\bar{x}=e\in G/P$.

If $|P|\neq p^n$, then $G/P$ has an element of order $p^k$ for some $k$ by Cauchy's theorem (since the order of $G/P$ is a multiple of $p$ if $|P|\neq p^n$). Therefore $|P|=p^n$.

Comment: Let's of missing steps. You can fill out the minor details :D

Comment: The answer to b) is not what is asked here I don't think.  You need to show that $G/P$ has no elements of prime order.

Comment: @CPM Hopefully I fixed any confusion on b). I apologize.

Comment: Yes, looks better now.  :)  Another very nitpicky thing, but I believe you mean $|P|=p^n$ rather than $p^m$ for c).  Too minor of an edit for me to do.  Cheers.

Comment: @CPM Hahaha, yes you're right again. I will fix it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I like the rest above, so I just wanted to suggest an argument for b).

Suppose there is an $\overline{x} \in G/P$ with order $p$, then $(x+P)^p=P$.  But this means $x^p \in P$, so $(x^p)^{p^k}=e$ for some $k$.  But this means $x\in P$ and thus $\overline{x}$ is actually the identity in $G/P$.  But the identity cannot have order $p$, so this is not possible.